# The maximum allowed API amount of monthly API requests has been reached

Tags: laravel, fixer.io

I am using exchanger api `(florianv/laravel-swap)` for foreign currency exchange rates in my laravel Project.

my `composer.json` snipped for relevance :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "florianv/laravel-swap": "^1.3",
},
```

While the api is giving values in my local environment, it is throwing an exception in production environment.

```
    The chain resulted in 2 exception(s): 
    Exchanger\Exception\Exception: The maximum allowed API amount of 
    monthly API requests has been reached. 
    Exchanger\Exception\Exception: The currency is not supported or 
    Google changed the response format
```

The Error is pretty clear on itself. But before I upgrade the  api plan, I thought I would try with another api key, I got a free api key from fixer.io and inserted it in `config/swap.php` file in my project.

```
/*Config/Swap.php*/
'services' => [
    'fixer' => [
        'access_key' => 'MY_ACCESS_KEY', // Your app id
    ],
    'google' => true,
],
```

The error still persists.

Am i supposed to enter the key somewhere else? How is it working on my local environment and not in the production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose an other service instead google.

- https://github.com/florianv/laravel-swap/issues/51
- https://github.com/florianv/laravel-swap/issues/35

or you can use the latest version and follow the doc.